# I need add some properties to existing classes but I can't modify them

Tags: c#

I have classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I can't modify these classes. My method:

```
public static void DoSomething(IList<Customer> customers)
```

gets data and now I need to add to this data ID for each item (id first customer should be = for example 10, id first order should be = for example 50). So:
**first customer should have id = 10, the first order of this customer should have id = 50 and customerId = 10, the second order of this customer should have id = 51 and customerId = 10 etc**

I have written this code below but it is horrible, is better way??:

```
public class Customer2 : Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public new List<Order2> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order2 : Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public static void DoSomething(IList<Customer> customers)
    {
        var customers2 = new List<Customer2>();

        var customerId = 10;
        var orderId = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentCustomer = customers[i];
            var currentCustomerOrders = currentCustomer.Orders;

            var orders2 = new List<Order2>();

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < currentCustomerOrders.Count; i2++)
            {
                var currentCustomerOrder = currentCustomerOrders[i2];

                orders2.Add(new Order2 { Id = orderId, CustomerId = customerId, Name = currentCustomerOrder.Name });

                orderId++;
            }

            customers2.Add(new Customer2 { Id = customerId, FirstName = currentCustomer.FirstName, LastName = currentCustomer.LastName, Orders = orders2 });

            customerId++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing totally wrong with this method in general. If you can't modify the class itself (which is often the case), this is a good solution.  I'd suggest trying `foreach` loops to help clean some of that up though.

Comment: The duplicate list is dangerous - better to simply stick Order2 instances into the existing list. Otherwise the list of orders is different depending on the variable type.

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: `I need add some properties to existing classes but I can't modify them` - Create a derived class ;)

Comment: You've already solved your own problem. Inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it looks you're on the right track except the duplicate list as @Marc noted in comments.

Here are some points to consider.

- If you need to add functionality to a class which you own source, modify the class itself.
- If you need to modify the class which you don't have source? Sub-class it.
- If you need to modify the class which you don't have source and also it is sealed? Use [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
- If you just need to add some methods for class to which you don't have a source? Use [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)